# Find NearBy App Not Working

Tags: app

After following all instructions and  installing  Find Nearby I attempted to geo code the accounts and the screen comes back saying "Locating accounts...do not close this window" with a large blank box and it appears nothing is happening.

I've tried geocoding from the geocode tab and by clicking on Locate Account but neither works.  I just keep getting the message "Locating Accounts do not close this window" with the blank box.

I tried in IE, chrome and firefox browsers but is the same issue. Can you please tell me what  browser setting needs to be change to make it work in IE or chrome.

Thanks in advance
Gaurav